# The userActivity function doesn't get called in AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, spotlight

When I tap on the result of the Core Spotlight search, the app launches, but the function in `AppDelegate.swift` doesn't get called:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
  print("called")
}
```

which contains a logic for navigating to a specific view controller and loading data.

Some people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214733/application-continue-useractivity-method-not-called-in-ios-13) seem to recommend using `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
 print("called"
}
```

but doesn't get called from Core Spotlight, either.

The only functions that seem to be being called are:

```swift
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {}
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {}
```

in `SceneDelegate.swift`, but doesn't have the needed `userActivity` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Not strictly the correct answer, this is for SwiftUI**, but incase others land here!

Took me ages to find this, so despite being an old question, thought I should add the answer that worked for me!

I found the answer here: https://betterprogramming.pub/implement-core-spotlight-in-a-swiftui-app-859cb703f55d

Rather than an `AppDelegate` function, it is just added as an modifier to the main content view:

```swift
.onContinueUserActivity(CSSearchableItemActionType) { userActivity in
    if let uniqueIdentifier = Int(userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String ?? "") {
        print("id: \(uniqueIdentifier)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the question is not about SwiftUI.

Comment: Oh - missed that :/  However Google brought be here with SwiftUI in my search; so may help others!