# "Instance method nearly matches optional requirement" in Swift when it should be a perfect match

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

In my AppDelegate, I have a method

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

However, I get the following warning:
[image]

The original code from that method came from an Apple sample, then I did other attempts by copy/pasting the method definition from the protocol file, also, using AppCode, I just did an override/implement.

Everytime, XCode ends up telling me it's nearly a match.

I created a brand new project, added that method to the AppDelegate, no problem. I then take the entire content of the AppDelegate, paste it into my other project, and there, AppCode tells me again it's nearly a match.

Has anyone ever met that? Any suggestion on how to convince XCode/the compiler that this is really the method it says it is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58214733/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be linked to an Apple bug, discussed here: [Xcode 8 Warning "Instance method nearly matches optional requirement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495773/xcode-8-warning-instance-method-nearly-matches-optional-requirement)

Doing what's advised in that question solved the underlying issue of the method not being called... Add this:

```
@objc(application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:)
```